# Approximate continous function with linear growth condition by Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, approximation, uniform-convergence

Suppose a continuous function $f(u)<K(1+|u|)$ for some positive number
$K$. How can we find a sequence of Lipschitz functions $f_{n}$ that
converge to $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. If we require $f(u)<K(1+|u|^{\gamma})$
for $\gamma>1$, then the uniform convergency would be changed to
just convergency by point limit? My idea is to use the cutoff function
to approximate it. But I do not know how to prove the uniformly convergency
using the assumption on $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following. For $n>K$, consider the function $f_n(x)=\sup_{u\in\mathbb R} (f(u)-n|u-x|)$. Then check that

- $f_n$ is well defined (supremum is attained and is finite)
- $f_n$ is Lipschitz
- $f_n\ge f$
- $f_n\to f$ pointwise ... uniformity is not so clear.

In fact, I don't believe in uniform approximation. The function $f(u) = \sin u^2$ obviously satisfies the given bound, but for any Lipschitz function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have $\sup|f-g|\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above is proven in San Martin and Lepeltier paper.

Comment: Please elaborate: In what publication? in what year? For your information, "link only" answers, as well as "citation only" answers are to be avoided. And here, you don't even have a complete citation.